# Tree menu in html

Tags: html, css

i'm just new in here and programming skill is less than all of you.
i have a problem, how i can create a dynamic tree menu with collapse ability without using javascript?

i'm sorry before, after i googling,i still confuse how exactly it create. so please help me.
i appreciate your attention guys.

Comment: `"a dynamic tree menu .. without using javascript"` - are you sure you can't use JavaScript? It's going to be difficult without it.

Comment: I've found [this amazing tutorial](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu). Have you tried it?

Comment: Not sure you can do collapsing effects without JavaScript at all. HTML by itself is pretty static.

Comment: ohh,,oke,,i will try it..

Comment: Note that it won't work in IE8. You need IE9+

Comment: CSS can give you nested popup menus...